# Wondering how to detect specific bluetooth devices

Tags: python

I own a Timex Move+ 50 watch with bluetooth capabilities.

When I activate the sync feature, I can find my watch on bluetooth (with the Pi, and my Android devices.)

I am trying to run a function when my watch is detected by my Raspberry Pi.

I tried this code (NOW UPDATED based on an answer):

```
import Bluetooth

target_name = '{Name of my bluetooth device}'
target_address = None

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()
for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name(bdaddr):
        target_address = bdaddr
        break

if target_address is not None:
     print("Found watch."), target_address
else:
     print("Watch was not found.")
```

However, it is printing that it <s>found my watch when the bluetooth is not on (and the Pi bluetooth settings or Android device cannot find it)</s> With the updated code, it cannot find my watch, even though the Pi can in available devices.  I also tried pairing with it, it was successful, but the code still said it couldn't find it.

**UPDATE:** I tried this with my phone, and it works - so I'm wondering why it doesn't work with my watch.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've played around with bluetooth quite a fair bit for the pi's and what I tended to find was the bluetooth standards weren't always *quite* adhered to by the manufacturers. Even just scanning for bluetooth devices every 30 seconds and logging an ID was problematic and sporadic at best.

Comment: How come the Pi can detect the watch but Python can't though?

Comment: What I found was your mileage varied depending on the libraries. I was using a python library and it downright failed at interacting with most Bluetooth speakers & phones but was successful in connecting to my old X301.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found out my watch uses Bluetooth Low Energy (Also known as Bluetooth Smart or Bluetooth 4.0 or BLE).

The Raspberry Pi doesn't support BLE devices, which makes me wonder how it can detect it on some levels.

Scratch that, you just need to enable an experimental setting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your coding logic is flawed. Here's what I'm seeing happening:

1. You are setting `target_address` to the bluetooth address of your
   watch.
2. Then you are getting into that `for loop`, and if you are finding your watch by name, you are setting `target_address` to your watch. If you don't find your watch, you're not doing anything to `target_address`, which was already set to your watch at the beginning, and still will be set to your watch even though you didn't find it.
3. Then you're getting into you last `if statement`. At this point, `target_address` has been set to your watch whether it's been found or not, so your code will always report the watch as being found.

Here's what you should change:
At the very beginning, set `target_address` to none. The only way this will change is if your `for loop` finds the watch.

Comment: Thanks - it's now saying it can't find my device.  However, even when my device's bluetooth is on, and the raspberry pi can detect it, it still says it's not found.  I also tried pairing it, and even though the connection was successful, it still said it wasn't found.